# Matching strings before and after a symbol

Tags: r, string

| Col 1 | Dummy |
| --- | --- |
| F25J2205/02 | 1 |
| F33J 4416/07 | 0 |

I am trying to create the above: If I have at least one integer before the `'/'` that is an integer after the `'/'`, then `1`, else `0`. I am trying to do this for a large dataset also.

From the above, we see that there are a few **2**'s before the `'/'`, and we also have a **2** after the `'/'`. thus I use `1`. Not the case with the second row so `0`.

Note I have 8 digits before the `'/'` in the example. This may not be the case i.e. it may be 5, 2 etc.
Also may be important to note that I have gaps ie breaks within my variables.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `0` also in your rule? E.g. `F03J4416/07`, there is a `0` before and after the '/'. Dose it match your rule?

Comment: Hi, yes it is. thanks for your answer. But now i am applying this to my actual dataset and I get  'Error in base::intersect(x, y, ...) : 
argument "y" is missing, with no default'.    Do you know what is going on? your strategy works when i use a sample of it

Comment: Maybe there are some strings without the `'/'` symbol in it. You can check which strings don't have `'/'` by `which(!grepl('/', df$Col))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** After clarification OP and @Darren Tsai. In case `0` counts also for the rule we could do it this way:

```
#data
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Col1    Dummy
F25J2205/02     1
F33J4416/07     0
F03J4416/07     1", header = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  separate(Col1, c("a", "b"), remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(Dummy = if_else(str_detect(a, paste0(strsplit(b, "")[[1]], collapse = "|")), 1, 0), 
         .keep = "unused")
```

output:

```
         Col1 Dummy
1 F25J2205/02     1
2 F33J4416/07     0
3 F03J4416/07     1
```

**First answer:**

Here is another option:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  separate(Col1, c("a", "b"), remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(Dummy = if_else(str_detect(a, as.character(parse_number(b))), 1, 0), 
         .keep = "unused")
```

```
        Col1 Dummy
1 F25J2205/02     1
2 F33J4416/07     0
```

Comment: I think you cannot parse `02` as `2` because the `0` also counts. Try this example: `"F03J4416/07"`. Your method cannot catch it.

Comment: @Darren Tsai. Thank you, good point as always. I will check it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with package `stringr`.

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Col1    Dummy
F25J2205/02     1
F33J4416/07     0", header = TRUE)

library(stringr)

createDummy <- function(x) {
  y <- sub("\\D(\\d+/\\d+)", "\\1", x)
  sapply(strsplit(y, "/"), \(x) {
    y <- str_split_1(x[1], "")
    +any(str_detect(x[2], y))
  })
}

createDummy(df1$Col1)
#> [1] 1 0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A `base` solution:

```r
df <- data.frame(Col = c("F25J2205/02", "F33J4416/07"))

df$dummy <- +(lengths(lapply(strsplit(df$Col, '/'), \(x) {
  do.call(intersect, strsplit(gsub('\\D', '', x), ''))
})) > 0)

df
#           Col dummy
# 1 F25J2205/02     1
# 2 F33J4416/07     0
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex solution:

First, we extract all digits from before `/0` that are getting repeated (note the use of backreference `\\1`) after `/0`, then we reduce the result to  a `unique` value, to finally see whether the result contains a `d`igit, in which case a `1` is awarded:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(Dummy = lapply(str_extract_all(Col, "(\\d)(?=.*/0\\1)"),
                        function(x) +str_detect(unique(x), "\\d")))
          Col Dummy
1 F25J2205/02     1
2 F33J4416/07
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(Col2 = str_remove_all(Col1, "[A-Z]+")) %>% 
  separate_wider_regex(Col2, c(lhs = "\\d+", "/", rhs = "\\d+")) %>% 
  mutate(rhs = str_replace(rhs, "(?<=\\d)(?=\\d)", "|")) %>% 
  transmute(Col1, dummy = +(str_detect(lhs, rhs)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Col1        dummy
  <chr>       <int>
1 F25J2205/02     1
2 F33J4416/07     0
3 F03J4416/07     1
```